# Convert pixels to coordinates

Tags: coordinate-system, aerial-photography, pixel

I have a vertical image with size (W,H). 
I have info about the coordinates in decimals of the the upper left and bottom right (Lat1,Lng1,Lat2,Lng2). 
I have the Ground Sample Distance (GSD) of the image in (pixel/m).
I want to know the coordinates of a pixel (x,y) in the image.

What is the best approach to do this?

The images I pretend to use are like this: 
[image]

Comment: Load it into QGIS and use the query tool.

Comment: there isn't a simple script?

Comment: How about you provide some more information? Usecase, further processing of coordinates, software, repetition, automation, etc.

Comment: Your problem is that you have an oblique image so the pixels along the bottom edge cover less area than the pixels along the top edge.  To answer your question you would need more information like the CCD size, the lens focal length, the z value of the camera, the pitch, roll, and yawl of the image.  Companies like Eagle View have software that can do this but in a highly controlled capture method.  Consider georeferencing the image in a GIS, take your measurements, and accept the margin of error.